# Left Shift not working for combination with [

Tags: keyboard

I have an Apple (wired aluminum) Keyboard (using with Mac mini).

Left `Shift + [` does not work (to type `{`). But Right `Shift + [` works.

Left `Shift` key is working for all the other keys.

I tried this keyboard with my laptop and the behavior is same.

I assumed it is hardware problem. I tried disconnecting and cleaning from outside and shaking off dust and debris.

What other measures should I take to correct this malfunction? or this keyboard is gonna die?

One of the other strange behavior is on USB connection, the keyboard automatically types `-` until I presses a key. (only on Mac Mini)

Comment: I found the [Keyboard Ghosting Explained](https://www.microsoft.com/appliedsciences/antighostingexplained.mspx) and after testing with some key combination there my key left `shift+[` to type `{` is working again.

Comment: I am having the same problem. How did you fix it?

Comment: @gdaniel press the key combinations described in the link. It is too much to include in here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it was Keyboard Ghosting problem. You can read more [here](https://www.microsoft.com/appliedsciences/antighostingexplained.mspx)

The problem was solved after I have tried pressing the key combinations (involving non-working key, in my case `[`).

There are a lot of combinations and so I don't include it here. In case it disappeared, here is the [archive version on the archive.org](https://web.archive.org/web/20170210105022/https://www.microsoft.com/appliedsciences/antighostingexplained.mspx).

Comment: This page also have the same information. https://geekdroids.com/keyboard-ghosting-explained/